# Could not find a required file, index.html while deploying to Netlify

Tags: html, reactjs, build, package.json, netlify

The public folder is in the right place, and yes I have tracked all files with Git, `index.html` is available and in the right place, that's why this error doesn't seem to make sense to me.

```
$ yarn build
8:08:03 PM: yarn run v1.22.4
8:08:03 PM: $ react-scripts build
8:08:04 PM: Could not find a required file.
8:08:04 PM:   Name: index.html
8:08:04 PM:   Searched in: /opt/build/repo/public
8:08:04 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
8:08:04 PM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
8:08:04 PM: ​
8:08:04 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
8:08:04 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
8:08:04 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
8:08:04 PM: ​
8:08:04 PM:   Error message
8:08:04 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn build
8:08:04 PM: ​
8:08:04 PM:   Error location
8:08:04 PM:   In Build comma
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unfortunately made a very upsetting mistake, I was revamping from Gatsby and Gatsby `.gitignore` has the `public` directory listed, I forgot to remove the `public` in the `.gitignore` file, so the `public` directory wasn't being pushed to GitHub.